# osmdroid ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I searched for so long for a simple example on how to set an Overlay with a simple icon on my osmdroid-map, but couldn't find anything helpful..

So for now my code looks like this:

```
private void initOverlay(){
    ArrayList<OverlayItem> stationList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    stationList.add(new OverlayItem("Test", "test2", new GeoPoint(lastLoc.getLatitude(), lastLoc.getLongitude())));
    ItemizedOverlayWithBubble stationOl = new ItemizedOverlayWithBubble(this,stationList,mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(stationOl);
    mapView.invalidate();
}
```

When I run my app, I get a ResourceNotFoundException and "ItemizedOverlayWithBubble" is crossed out in eclipse..

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project, and add all the missing imports?

Comment: Yes, I just cleaned it and nothing changed. the imports are there for sure ;)

Comment: What says the red cross in eclipse in `"ItemizedOverlayWithBubble"`?

Comment: there is no red cross - it's that orange warning-symbol (because of suppress-warnings), but the written code is crossed out with a line through `ItemizedOverlayWithBubble`.

Comment: The crossed out line just means that `ItemizedOverlayWithBubble` is deprecated. According to the [source](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/trunk/OSMBonusPack/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/overlays/ItemizedOverlayWithBubble.java) you should use `Marker` instead.

Comment: Yes, use Marker instead, and follow the tutorial (https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0)

Comment: Thank you guys so much!!
I was searching for about 4 days and didn't find anything..